# Swift3: Eventos de TextField en TableViewCell

Tags: swift3, uitableview, uitableviewcell

Cordial saludo.
Trabajo en una aplicación la cual tiene una lista de elementos, cada item de la lista esta compuesta un celda personalizada (TableViewCell) la cual contiene 1 textfield y varios labels. Intento capturar el evento value change del textfield en la celda. Hasta el momento tengo este código pero no logro capturar el evento...Alguna idea?

**TableViewCell**

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var imagen: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var producto: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var precio: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cantidad: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet weak var stock: UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        cantidad?.delegate = self
        self.contentView.addSubview(cantidad!)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @IBAction func txtCantidad_onChange(_ sender: Any) {
        if cantidad?.text != "0" {
           print("Cambio con valor != a 0")
        }else{
            print("Cambio con valor 0")
        }
    }
}
```

El código que se muestra arriba es solo un ejemplo, pero en realidad deseo ejecutar todo el código del método **didSelectRowAt** de la tableView

El código de inicio de la tabla se aloja en un ViewController independiente

**ViewController**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrProductosDetalle.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let celda = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ProductoViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ProductoViewCell
            let aux = arrProductos[indexPath.row] as! Producto

            let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: aux.imagen, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
            let decodedimage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded as Data)!
            celda.imagen.image = decodedimage
            celda.producto.text = aux.nombre
            celda.precio.text = "Precio: $\(Formato().Double2String(valor: aux.precioVenta))"
            celda.stock.text = "En stock \((arrProductos[indexPath.row] as! Producto).stock)"
            return celda
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let celda = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            let aux = arrProductos[indexPath.row] as! Producto

            if (celda?.isSelected)! {
                if  (celda as! ProductoViewCell).cantidad?.text != "" {
                    if ((celda as! ProductoViewCell).cantidad?.text?.isInt)! && (celda as! ProductoViewCell).cantidad?.text != "0"{
                        if Int(((celda as! ProductoViewCell).cantidad?.text)!)! <= aux.stock
                        {
                            let nuevo: PedidoDetalle = PedidoDetalle()
                            nuevo.idProducto = aux.id;
                            nuevo.precioUnitario = aux.precioVenta
                            nuevo.cantidad = Int(((celda as! ProductoViewCell).cantidad?.text)!)!
                            nuevo.precioSubtotal = (nuevo.precioUnitario * Double(nuevo.cantidad))
                            nuevo.idParametrizacion = 1
                            arrProductosDetalle.add(nuevo)
                            lstPedidoDetalle.reloadData()
                            lblTotal.text = Formato().Double2String(valor: calcularTotal())
                            celda?.accessoryType = .checkmark
                        }else{
                            celda?.isSelected = false
                            Mensaje().mensaje(controller: self,texto: "El stock no es suficiente")
                        }
                    }else{
                        celda?.isSelected = false
                        (celda as! ProductoViewCell).cantidad?.text = ""
                        Mensaje().mensaje(controller: self, texto: "Tipo de dato no valido o valor no valido")
                    }
                }else{
                celda?.isSelected = false
                Mensaje().mensaje(controller: self,texto: "Primero defina la cantidad de este producto")}
            }else{

            }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView == lstPedidos{
            let celda = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            let aux = arrProductos[indexPath.row] as! Producto
            let nuevo: PedidoDetalle = PedidoDetalle()
            nuevo.idProducto = aux.id;
            nuevo.precioUnitario = aux.precioVenta
            nuevo.cantidad = Int(((celda as! ProductoViewCell).cantidad?.text)!)!
            nuevo.precioSubtotal = (nuevo.precioUnitario * Double(nuevo.cantidad))
            //arrPedidoProducto.add(nuevo)
            for item in arrProductosDetalle
            {
                let aux = item as! PedidoDetalle
                if(aux.idProducto == nuevo.idProducto && aux.cantidad == nuevo.cantidad)
                {
                    arrProductosDetalle.remove(aux)
                }
            }
            //arrProductosDetalle.removeObject(identicalTo: nuevo)
            (celda as! ProductoViewCell).cantidad?.text = ""
            celda?.accessoryType = .none
            lstPedidoDetalle.reloadData()
            lblTotal.text = Formato().Double2String(valor: calcularTotal())

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguro que hay más formas de hacerlo pero esto es lo que haría yo.

Primero quitar la función txtCantidad_onChange de la clase de la celda y ponerlo en el viewController

Segundo añadir el target a los UITextField cuando se crea cada celda y añadirle un tag correspondiente a la línea de la celda (row) para facilitar trabajo más adelante

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let celda = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ProductoViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ProductoViewCell
        let aux = arrProductos[indexPath.row] as! Producto

        let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: aux.imagen, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
        let decodedimage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded as Data)!
        celda.imagen.image = decodedimage
        celda.producto.text = aux.nombre
        celda.precio.text = "Precio: $\(Formato().Double2String(valor: aux.precioVenta))"
        celda.stock.text = "En stock \(aux.stock)"
        celda.cantidad.tag = indexPath.row
        celda.cantidad.addTarget(self, action: #selector(txtCantidad_onChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        return celda
}
```

Tercero modificar la función txtCantidad_onChange para que modifique el objeto Producto que le corresponde (sabemos cuál es gracias al tag que añadimos antes). Al estar tratando con objetos lo que modifiques en aux afectará al objeto original de la lista.

```
func txtCantidad_onChange(_ textFieldCantidad: UITextField) {
    let aux = arrProductos[textFieldCantidad.tag] as! Producto
    if textFieldCantidad.text != "0" {
       print("Cambio con valor != a 0")
       //aux.cantidad = textFieldCantidad.text
    }else{
        print("Cambio con valor 0")
    }
}
```

En la función didSelectRow puedes evitar escribir `celda as! ProductoViewCell` tantas veces si lo pones al principio

```
let celda = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ProductoViewCell
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me salvaste, en la función txtCantidad_onChange agregue ademas un linea para obtener el index path de una manera mas general let `indexPath = IndexPath(row: textFieldCantidad.tag, section: 0)`